# How to paint a gradient with TexDraw brush?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, texture-painting

In texture painting mode, the TexDraw brush has a functional "Use Gradient" checkbox (functionnal meaning it will actually let you chose a gradient, compared with the Smear brush for instance which does not). However, I can't seem to make it work in pressure mode: it only paints with the rightmost color. Repeat mode works by making selecting colors randomly within the gradient and clamp mode uses one color on clicking and the other on dragging (I have no idea why anyone would want to use it this way...)

Basically I would like to make it work with the stroke set to "Line", that is being able to draw a straight line whose color is that of the gradient. Can this be done? The only brush that seems to work with gradients is the Fill brush, but I just need to draw lines, not to fill an area.

Answer (score 2):

Strokes set to Line do not give you the ability to see a gradient travel along it, or curve for that matter. TexBrush with gradient and pressure in the Strength ticked on (be sure to adjust the strength to allow for some fluctuation) can be useful for changing the color along the gradient ramp, but then it is really about using your manual stroke here to control the pressure - wit hthat, I sometimes play with the Shift-S Smooth Stroke or Lazy Stroke to control my line/curve while painting.

Answer (score 2):

In version 2.79 Gradient works with Stroke set to 'line' MOST of the time, but only if 'mode' is set to 'repeat'. However there seems to be a bug that makes only one colour (colour from the right side of the gradient colours) appear.
To make all colours appear along the line change the value of 'gradient spacing'. Default is '1', but change the value to any random number,  paint, then change back to default or any other value, the gradient colours  paint along the line.